# query the number of non-unique elements in table

Tags: mysql, database, oracle

Let `NUM` be the number of CITY entries in STATION, and `NUMunique` be the number of unique cities. Query the value of `NUM−NUMunique` from STATION.

In other words, query the number of non-unique CITY names in STATION by subtracting the number of unique CITY entries in the table from the total number of CITY entries in the table, which has this structure:

[image]

where LAT_N is the northern latitude and LONG_W is the western longitude.

I have this query but it returns the wrong output.

```
SELECT SUM(COUNT(CITY)) 
FROM STATION 
GROUP BY CITY 
HAVING COUNT(CITY)>1; b
```

Comment: chk the image mg to know the structure of the table

Comment: i use the query SELECT SUM(COUNT(CITY)) FROM STATION
GROUP BY CITY
HAVING COUNT(CITY)>1; but its showing wrong output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

select count(*) - count(distinct uniquevalue) from table;

You need to determine an expression which identifies a city uniquely.  Is it the name?  Is it a combination of LAT_N and LONG_W?  You might use something like (1000*LAT_N + LONG_W), for example.

Comment: it didn't come to my mind to use like this .. i was trying in complicated way with wrong results.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following query:

```
SELECT COUNT(CITY)- COUNT(DISTINCT CITY) FROM STATION;
```